# Django: How do I use a different form_class with django-registration

Tags: django, django-forms

I want [django-registration (version 0.8)](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/) to use my custom form rather than the default one. However, I want to continue to use the default django-registration view. What should the rest of the line below look like to achieve this?

```
(r'^accounts/register'...),
```

I've tried this below but get a syntax error:

```
(r'^accounts/register/$', 
         'registration.views.register', 
         {'form_class': 'MyRegistrationForm'}, name='registration_register'),
```

And when I try this one below I get register() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

```
(r'^accounts/register/$',      
    'registration.views.register',             
    {'form_class':'MyRegistrationForm'}),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `views.register` function,

```
def register(request, backend, success_url=None, form_class=None,
             disallowed_url='registration_disallowed',
             template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
             extra_context=None):
```

you can see that `backend` is a required argument. Try the following:

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', 
         'registration.views.register', 
         {'form_class': MyRegistrationForm,
          'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'},
         name='registration_register'),
```

note that you need to use `url(r'^...)` if you wish to name your url.

Comment: Just needed to change to registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'and it worked. Many thanks!