# django registration redux clean clean password

Tags: django, registration, data-cleaning

I am using django 1.8.2 and python 2.7

I am a novice in django. I am using django registration redux to authenticate the users. I want to manually define a clean method on the password field to ensure the password is atleast 6 character long, and contains at least one numeric n one special character. How to do that? Shall I define a form inheriting from the RegistrationForm class? or is it easier to change something in the RegistrationForm itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to override the behavior instead of modifying the source code so simply subclass RegistrationForm. It is actually recommended in the comments :

*Form for registering a new user account.
Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.
Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
need, but should avoid defining a `save()` method -- the actual
saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
registration backend.*

Comment: can you explain a little more how (and where) i define this subclass? or point me to some document that already explains that. do i define a new form class in forms.py? how to make the registration.views to accept this form instead of the default one?

Comment: The form can live anywhere in your project, preferably in a `forms.py` file.       [The new form should be passed as an argument to the registration view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205288/django-how-do-i-use-a-different-form-class-with-django-registration "Meta")